# сортировка координат с одинаковыми координатами - x

Tags: javascript

У меня есть два массива.

```
let X = [1,3,2,2,3,4,1,3];
let Y = [2,4,2,4,2,2,1,3];
```

Сначала я его сортирую на основе игриков по убыванию.

```
// sortY
for (let i = 0; i < Y.length; i++) {
    let minIndex = i;
    for (let j = i + 1; j < Y.length; j++) {
        if (Y[j] > Y[minIndex]) {
            minIndex = j;
        }
    }
    let tempX = X[i];
    let tempY = Y[i];
    X[i] = X[minIndex];
    Y[i] = Y[minIndex];
    X[minIndex] = tempX;
    Y[minIndex] = tempY;
}
```

Здесь внимание: так как это координаты, и их я изменять не могу, то вместе с `Y` всегда должен идти его же `X`. По этому не зависимо от того будет ли `Х[i]` посортированый, я все равно приписываю ему тот же `i` что и для сортированого `Y[i]`.
После сортировки я получаю следующий массив (координаты):

```
3 4
2 4
3 3
1 2
3 2
4 2
2 2
1 1
```

Как теперь можна еще посортировать только те координаты (по убыванию) относительно `X[i]` у которых одинаковый `Y[i]`?
Ожидаемый результат:

```
3 4
2 4
3 3
4 2
3 2
2 2
1 2
1 1
```

Comment: Вам нужно написать функцию сравнения (которая будет использоваться вместо простого `>`), которая сравнивает сначала Y, а при из равенстве ещё и X. В JS наверняка есть встроенная функция сортировки, которой нужно подсунуть соответствующую функцию сравнения

Comment: @MBo вроде метод `every` или `filter`.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Выбирать данные задача не стоит, для сортировки есть sort

Comment: @qqq https://jsfiddle.net/EzioMercer/wLex62vn/2/